# gnuplot horizontal space before first line point and after last

Tags: gnuplot

using: gnuplot 4.2 patchlevel 6

I am plotting candlesticks.  The first and last data points are, of course, on the left and right Y axis bars.  The first and last candlesticks are all but hidden by the axis bars.  a la:

```
set terminal gif
set xtics rotate
plot    "test.csv" u 0:3:xtic(1) t "Avg" with lines, \
        "test.csv" u 0:4:5:6:7 t "MinMax&Stdv" with candlesticks
```

[image]

Is there a way to "fake" a null starting and ending point?  I have tried adding zero values but that just grounds the plotted line(s) at the start and end.

Comment: Can you try `set xrange [-1:11]` ?

Comment: aesthetically, I like this answer best but both work very well.  Thank you both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what `set offsets` is for: Add some offsets to gnuplots autoscaled range:

**Without offsets** (this is your case):

```
$data <<EOD
1 1
2 2
EOD
plot $data with lp pt 7 ps 2 notitle
```

[image]

**With offsets in x-direction**:

```
$data <<EOD
1 1
2 2
EOD
set offsets 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0
plot $data with lp pt 7 ps 2 notitle
```

[image]

As you can see, you get offsets at the left and right plot margins. However, the margin's size isn't `0.1` in units of the first axis, but the value is rounded to the next auto-generated tic.

To work around this, you can add `set autoscale xfix`:

```
$data <<EOD
1 1
2 2
EOD
set offsets 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0
set autoscale xfix
plot $data with lp pt 7 ps 2 notitle
```

[image]