# Gnuplot set autoscale xmax to always leave a gap from y2axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot script which works fine. I am plotting the last point label to the right of the point but the space at the end of the xaxis always change and I haven't figure out how to keep a consistent space so the label is always visible.

The data file is something like this, with 100 data points:

```
171030 784750
171031 787000
171101 773000
171102 798000
171103 784000
171106 794000
171107 781000
171108 785000
171109 788000
171110 794000
171113 793125
171114 795000
171115 795000
171116 794000
171117 776000
...
```

This is my script:

```
set term pngcairo size 766,400 enhanced
set output outfile

set xdata time
set timefmt "%y%m%d"
flabel(y)=sprintf("$%'.0f", y)

set format y "%'.0f"

set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror

set border 3 # Draw only the left and bottom

set grid linewidth 1
set grid linecolor "#222222"

pic_color="#4682B4"

set autoscale xfixmin

plot infile using 1:2 with lines linewidth 2 linecolor rgb pic_color notitle , \
infile every ::99 using 1:2:(flabel($2)) with labels point pointtype 7 linecolor rgb pic_color offset character 4,character 0 textcolor rgb pic_color notitle
```

I run it with:

```
gnuplot -e "infile='171030.dat';outfile='171030.png'" script.gp
```

I have tried to use `set autoscale xfixmax` but it removes the space and I can't find how to set it to a fix amount.

If I let `xmax` to `autoscale`, sometimes it leaves enough space to show the label but sometimes not.

I tried Christoph suggestions on the comments, but no results:

No autoscale:

```
# set autoscale xfixmin
set offsets graph 0, 0.1, 0, 0
```

[image]

With autoscale xfix:

```
set autoscale xfix
set offsets graph 0, 0.1, 0, 0
```

[image]

With autoscale xfixmin:

```
set autoscale xfixmin
set offsets graph 0, 0.1, 0, 0
```

[image]

The results are the same no matter what value I use for the right offset or if I use set `offsets graph 0, 0.1, 0, 0` or `offsets 0, 0.1, 0, 0` or If I just leave it without the `offsets`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47218522/2604213

Comment: @Christoph Seems like it is what I need, but haven't been able to make it work. I tried: `set offsets 0, 5, 0, 0` with and without `set autoscale xfix`, but the result is just as if I didn't set any offsets. Any ideas on what could I be doing wrong? I even tried `set offsets 0, 50, 0, 0` but the plot is the same as if I remove the offsets, they just don't change anything.

Comment: @Christoph I really appreciate you take the time to read my question and that you are trying to point me in the right direction, but I haven't been able to make it work. Could you please read my question again? I updated with some test I made implementing your suggestions.

Comment: `set autoscale xfix; set offsets 0, graph 0.2` will extend the range of the x axis by 20% over the date range covered in the data file. Note that the `graph` keyword modifies the second argument to `set offsets`. Alternatively you can extend the range by, say, 10 days using `set offsets 0, 10*24*60*60`.

Comment: @user8153 Got it! Thanks for the explanation. Could you please post your comment as an answer. It is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend the range of the x axis by, say, 20% over the range covered in the data file, use

```
set autoscale xfix
set offsets 0, graph 0.2
```

If instead you want to extend the range by a fixed amount, for examples 10 days, use

```
set autoscale xfix
set offsets 0, 10*24*60*60
```