# How do I add an empty space at the beginning of the x and y axis?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I wrote a script to get graphs similar to this one, using gnuplot:

[image]

How do I add some empty space at the beginning of the x-axis and y-axis? I want something like the following graph:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47218522/2604213

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options. @Christof links you to one that uses offsets. Also, presuming you set the xtics (you should include your code as that helps us help you), you can set the xrange to just miss the next tics. For example, assuming you `set xtics 0.05`, you can:

```
set xrange [-0.351:0.149]
```

This is a quick and easy way to give yourself a little whitespace. Notice it does not quite reach the next ticmark.

Alternatively, you can directly set xrange and yrange as big as you want, then specify in this order, a start location, an increment, and an end location for the tic marks:

```
set xrange [-0.4:.2]
set xtics -0.3,0.05,0.1
```